# Laravel Migration taking too long

Tags: mysql, laravel, performance, migration

I'm facing a weird experience with Laravel Migration.

I've run 2 migrations the first one passed in less than second. 
The second is taking a long time and still running for more than 10 minutes untill I killed it.

It's not a big deal, just adding 2 columns to a table that contains 23 entries. Yes, only 23 entries.

the query itslef is very simple :

```
Schema::table('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->boolean('public')->default(0);
            $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
        });
```

Any clue ? I'm missing anything ?

Is it because I already have 30 columns in the table ?

==== Edit ====

As asked, here are the other migration that passed

```
class UpdateUsers extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('shop_id')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

the one that is not working

```
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->boolean('public')->default(0);
            $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Having thirty columns in a table is a bad design. But still it should not take 10 minutes. Can you share your whole migrations? Both of them

Comment: I havve added the 2 migrations. Do you see anything ?

Comment: Do you need to preserve data or is `artisan migrate:fresh` an option?

Comment: i can run it in dev but definitely not in production. So yes I need to run preserve data

Comment: No, 30 columns is not a problem.  Do you have the generated SQL?

Comment: @RickJames. thanks for commenting. It's fine, I have answered the issue. It's the MySQL server that was not responding

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I understand what's going on.
I had some slowness when performing some requests. So I thought about the MySQL serve.

I restarted it and then launched the same migration that used not to work and it went perfect (0.07 seconds).

I think checked and / or restarting the BD server is something to check systematically as well as checking the syntax and table structure.

Cheers

Comment: Saved my time and life - thank you so much!